# Bootstrap collapse doesn't stay open after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have laravel and vue js installed and using bootstrap. I am trying to use bootstrap collapse. But when I click to open the collapsed item it opens for some milisecond and then disappear. Here is my code

```
<a href="#demo" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

I tried to use `$('.collapse').collapse();` but it doesn't make any effect if comment this line or keep it. Sane result.

Any idea what's wrong? Also there is no error in the console.

Thank you

Comment: Please post some code snippet replicating the issue...

Comment: This same code works in a normal set up but doesn't work with laravel vue set up. and unfortunately it's not possible to get snippets with laravel vue.

Answer (score 2):

**You have missed data-target attribute & not needed to set href tag for a tag.**

 check below snippet for working code.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</a>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works normally but when paste the code in vue template it doesn't

Comment: may be any other version of js source file added & it may create the issue.
check your list of added .js files.

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it by just adding the right JS to the bootstrap. I was using Bootstrap v4.3 and the JS was V3.31. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to maulik's answer:

If you are using v4, make sure your jquery/bootstrap.min.js is the correct version.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```